# Filtering dataclass instances by unique attribute value

Tags: python, filtering, python-dataclasses

I have a list of dataclass instances in the form of:

```
dataclass_list = [DataEntry(company="Microsoft", users=["Jane Doe", "John Doe"]), DataEntry(company="Google", users=["Bob Whoever"]), DataEntry(company="Microsoft", users=[])]
```

Now I would like to filter that list and get only unique instances by a certain key (company in this case).

The desired list:

```
new_list = [DataEntry(company="Microsoft", users=["Jane Doe", "John Doe"]), DataEntry(company="Google", users=["Bob Whoever"])]
```

The original idea was to use a function in the fashion of python's `set()` or `filter()` functions, but both is not possible here.

My working solution so far:

```
tup_list = [(dataclass, dataclass.company)) for dataclass in dataclass_list]
new_list = []
check_list = []
for tup in tup_list:
    if tup[1].lower() not in check_list:
        new_list.append(tup[0])
        check_list.append(tup[1].lower())
```

This gives me the desired output but I was wondering whether there is a more pythonic or elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `DataEntry` dataclass you need to override [`__eq__(...)`](https://%7BCompany(name=%27Google%27,%20location=%27Palo%20Alto%27),%20Company(name=%27Microsoft%27,%20location=%27Berlin%27),%20Company(name=%27IBM%27,%20location=%27San%20Francisco%27)%7D) and [`__hash__(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__eq#object.__hash__) functions, in which you specify which attribute is used when calculating the hash value of an object and when are two objects considered equal.

A short example in which the `name` attribute of the class `Company` is used by default for determining the equality of two objects. I have also extended your case with an option where you can determine the attribute which will be considered for uniqueness when constructing the object. Mind that **all objects** that will be compared need to have the same `comparison_attr`.

```
import pprint

class Company:

    def __init__(self, name, location, comparison_attr="name") -> None:
        # By default we use the attribute `name` for comparison
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.__comparison_attr = comparison_attr

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.__getattribute__(self.__comparison_attr))

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return self.__getattribute__(self.__comparison_attr) == other.__getattribute__(self.__comparison_attr)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"name={self.name}, location={self.location}"

for attribute_name in ["name", "location"]:
    companies = [
        Company("Google", "Palo Alto", comparison_attr=attribute_name), 
        Company("Google", "Berlin", comparison_attr=attribute_name),
        Company("Microsoft", "Berlin", comparison_attr=attribute_name),
        Company("Microsoft", "San Francisco", comparison_attr=attribute_name),
        Company("IBM", "Palo Alto", comparison_attr=attribute_name),
    ]

    print(f"Attribute considered for uniqueness: {attribute_name}")
    pprint.pprint(set(companies))
```

Output:

```
Attribute considered for uniqueness: name
{name=Microsoft, location=Berlin,
 name=Google, location=Palo Alto,
 name=IBM, location=Palo Alto}

Attribute considered for uniqueness: location
{name=Microsoft, location=San Francisco,
 name=Google, location=Berlin,
 name=Google, location=Palo Alto}
```

Comment: Really cool answer!

Comment: That was kind of the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I have made an extension to the example where you can dynamically determine the attribute being considered for uniqueness. Maybe this can further help you. :)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot for the great answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, whether or not you find that more elegant is up to you:

```
unique = {}
for dc in dataclass_list:
    if dc.company not in unique:
        unique[dc.company] = dc
new_list = list(unique.values())
```

Comment: Definitely more elegant than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and more readable solution is this:

```py
dataclass_list = [DataEntry(company="Microsoft", users=["Jane Doe", "John Doe"]), DataEntry(company="Google", users=["Bob Whoever"]), DataEntry(company="Microsoft", users=[])]

unique_companies = {data_entry.company: data_entry for data_entry in dataclass_list}

print(unique_companies.values())
# output: dict_values([DataEntry(company='Microsoft', users=[]), DataEntry(company='Google', users=['Bob Whoever'])])
```